# Is there a way to mask or proxy your IP in Craigslist?

Tags: proxy, ip, mask

For posting in Craigslist I want to make my IP appear like I'm in a specific state, and will be able to reboot it as well for the state. Let's say, for example , I am in Australia, but wants to post in Raleigh NC. In order to do that I need Raleigh NC IP, and in order to repost a couple of times a day, I need to reboot IP but for the same state, is there way?

Comment: Why do you want to do that, specifically?

Comment: Seems like this may be intentionally circumventing rules put in place by said service provider....

Comment: Question closed while I was answering it.  Your IP should not play into it.  If you need to post to a city other than your own, simply navigate to that city's page before posting, or select that city from the dropdown list when you do the posting.  I have posted between US states several times to help my father list things.  Just to be sure that there are no cross-country issues, I just posted something in Sydney without issues (and immediately deleted it...).  If you can't post from your area, then you or the ISP have probably been banned.

Answer (score 3):

From Craigslist Terms of use
http://www.craigslist.org/about/terms.of.use

> a.    Postings
>
> craigslist is intended and designed as a local service. A user may
>   post content only to the single specific geographic area offered on
>   craigslist (see http://www.craigslist.org/about/sites) for which that
>   content is most relevant. The same or substantially similar content
>   (for example, an ad for a particular item or service, a particular
>   offer, a particular message or a particular comment) may not be posted
>   to or communicated via more than one such geographic area. Content
>   that is equally relevant to multiple (i.e., more than one) geographic
>   areas should not be posted on craigslist.

And more...

> Users may not circumvent any technological measure implemented by CL to restrict the manner in which content may be posted on craigslist or to regulate the manner in which content (including but not limited to email) may be transmitted to other users. This prohibition includes, without limitation, a ban on the use of multiple email addresses (created via an email address generator or otherwise); the use of multiple IP addresses (via proxy servers, modem toggling, or otherwise); CAPTCHA circumvention, automation or outsourcing; multiple and/or fraudulent craigslist accounts, including phone-verified accounts; URL shortening, obfuscation or redirection; use of multiple phone lines or phone forwarding for verification; and content obfuscation via HTML techniques, printing text on images, inserting random text or content "spinning."